# jquery chained select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to do the simple usage on this link

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

but the second dropdown still show all the options. Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.chained.js"      charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
if (jQuery().chained) {  
alert('jQuery is loaded!');  
}
else{  
alert('jQuery is not loaded!');  
}
</script>

<select id="mark" name="mark">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="bmw">BMW</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
<option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
<option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
<option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
<option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
<option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
</select>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$("#series").chained("#mark");
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: put your code in document.ready funciton

Comment: it alerts that jquery(i forget to change the jquery to jquery.chained) is loaded

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/upefum/1 I just copied your code, pasted it in, and changed the library paths.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i see it works on you, i dont get it. its not working on me. im using notepad++,xampp and google chrome to view.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i put my jquery plugins on htdocs folder.

Comment: @ReginaldAngeloAnchetaTapan: (Just FWIW: Not working *for* you.) I don't know what to tell you. It works, as you can see from the link above. I've tried Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: omg it works after i put these <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>; and replace the jquery.js at first im using jquery.js modified at july 8 2008 (because of the other tutorials on how to create a chained combobox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to look if jquery is loaded or not, or try with cdn hosted jquery like below:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

This should be working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.chained.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script>
         if (jQuery().chained) {  
              alert('jQuery is loaded!');  
         }
          else{   
             alert('jQuery is not loaded!');  
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select id="mark" name="mark">
           <option value="">--</option>
           <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
           <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
      <select id="series" name="series">
           <option value="">--</option>
           <option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
           <option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
           <option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
           <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
           <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
           <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
      </select>

      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
          $("#series").chained("#mark");
      </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

What did you missed in the document is `</head> <body></body>`, Try this one or add these tags and see.

Comment: We know from the comments that jQuery and the plug-in are both loaded. And while those tags are definitely missing, [they're optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) and any half-decent browser (certainly Chrome, which the OP is using) will handle their absence. (I'd still put them in, I'm just saying...)

Comment: still the same even i put the </head> and the <body> </body>

Comment: omg it works after i put these <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> and replace the jquery.js

Comment: at first im using jquery.js (modified at july 8 2008)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Document.ready will invoke methods when DOM finises it's loading.

wrap your code in document.ready function

```
$(function(){
if (jQuery().chained) {  
alert('jQuery is loaded!');  
}
else{  
alert('jQuery is not loaded!');  
}
})
```

Comment: There's no need for that, the code is after the `script` tags that load jQuery and the plug-in. That's all that's required.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder he already has code after the libraries only

Comment: @ Ravi: Which is all that is required for the code you've put in `ready`.

Comment: how to declare it? sorry im a total newbie here.

Comment: @TJ wouldn't this is a good practice to wrap the code in `doc ready`.

Comment: @ReginaldAngeloAnchetaTapan: This answer is wrong. And in fact, your code works just fine.

Comment: @Jai: No. In fact, using `ready` outside of a library is almost never good practice. That's a popular myth. If you control where the `script` tag goes (e.g., you're not writing a library), you put the `script` tag at the end of `</body>`. No  need for the `ready` event. Google's Closure library engineers didn't even include one in their library, because they said it encourages poor practice.

Comment: @t.j. crowder but when im running it the second dropdown still show all the contents even i change the first one.

Comment: @ReginaldAngeloAnchetaTapan: Not for me: http://jsbin.com/upefum/1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i see it works on you, i dont get it my its not working on me. im using notepad++,xampp and google chrome to view.

Comment: @ReginaldAngeloAnchetaTapan: I've tried both Chrome and Firefox, works just fine.

Comment: @Jai: FWIW: [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [Google Closure engineers on why there's no `ready`-like event in Closure](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41).